# Spark range function to create id in existing dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, indexing

I am trying to figure out how to use `spark.range(1,10).toDF('id')` with an existing data frame to create an `id` column.

I tried using `withcolumn` with the following expression, but it doesn't work as it is not a column or list:

```py
spark.range(1,10).toDF('id')
```

Comment: That should work fine, `spark.range(0, 10).toDF("ID")` - what is your error exactly? Are you also importing: `import spark.implicits._` ?

Comment: `spark.range(1,10).toDF('id')` creates a new dataframe. use `row_number()` or `monotonically_increasing_id()` while creating a new column in existing dataframe.